# Plotting a P-value depending on the p-value in R

Tags: r, plot, format

I am trying to plot R2 and P-values on a regression plot in R with help from [this page](https://lukemiller.org/index.php/2012/10/adding-p-values-and-r-squared-values-to-a-plot-using-expression/). Here are my codes.

```
DF <- data.frame(X <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Y <- c(1.5, 2.1, 1.2, 4.4, 1, 6.5, 8.4))

plot(Y ~ X, data = DF)

# Add regression line
regline <- lm(DF$Y ~ DF$X)
intercept <- coef(regline)[1]
slope <- coef(regline)[2]
abline(regline)

# Get stats
summary(regline)

# Get these values
names(summary(regline))
# Get adjusted R-square
R2 <- summary(regline)$adj.r.squared

# Get pPvalue
P <- summary(regline)$coefficients[2,4]
P <- ifelse(P < 0.05, '< 0.05', P)

# Plot R2 and P-value
r2p = vector('expression', 2)
r2p[1] = substitute(expression(italic(R)^2 == RSQ), list(RSQ = format(R2, dig = 2)))[2]
r2p[2] = substitute(expression(italic(P) == PVALUE), list(PVALUE = format(P, digits = 2)))[2]
legend('topleft', legend = r2p, bty = 'n', y.intersp = 1.3)
```

What I want to do differently is to change the P-value to "P < 0.05" if the value is smaller than 0.05. I can convert the value but it still prints out the "=" sign like this.

[image]

How can I make it to print "P < 0.05" instead of "P =< 0.05" while keeping the italic P? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey~did my solution solve your problem?

Comment: @Darren Tsai, thank you for your help and sorry for the delay. I am trying out each of your options and checking ?plotmath() and demo(plotmath) but still not being able to print "P < 0.05" yet.

Comment: If I don’t misunderstand your request, you are trying to revise just the second line of the legend to P < 0.05 and other places remain, right? My code works for that in my computer so I don’t know what happened to you. Thanks for replying me. Good luck!

Comment: Please check my edit. I add my output. If that is not what you want, maybe I misunderstand your request and sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revise the expression in `r2p[2]` to one of the following forms:

- `expression(italic(P) ~ PVALUE)`
- `expression(italic(P) * PVALUE)`
- `expression(paste(italic(P), PVALUE))`

That is, put any of the codes above into the place `xxxxxx`:

```
r2p[2] = substitute(xxxxxx, list(PVALUE = format(P, digits = 2)))[2]
```

[image]

Please check `?plotmath` and `demo(plotmath)` for details.

Comment: I think I had your codes inserted in a wrong place. All three worked! Thank you so much!